# openvpn & apache & RDC running side by side

Tags: apache-2.2, remote-desktop, openvpn

I have a huge question so do be patient with me as I'm not an openvpn expert. :)

This is my Setup:

- OpenVpn installed on my home windows PC.
- When i'm not at home and at work I connect to my windows PC via RDC.
- Now, when I connect to my home pc via RDC and activate the OpenVpn connection there, my RDC connection get's disconnected and I can't log on again.
- My apache hosted website's IP which is hosted on my home pc, is no longer available. The only way get my site or RDC up
  is to go home and disconnect openvpn.

How do I get this set-up to work and is there some mod that can be applied to the settings in the ovpn config files?

I'm starting openvpn via commandline:

openvpn "path to ovpn config file"

Answer (score 0):

Why are you logging into your home computer via RDC then activating the OpenVPN tunnel? Once you start OpenVPN, it changes how everything is routed. This is probably why you are getting instantly disconnected once you start it up. You should have OpenVPN running all the time on your home computer and then VPN into your home computer. This method is a lot secure and in my opinion how you should do it.

You will still need to work on your OpenVPN configuration and see what routes are being pushed and verify you can get everywhere you need.